# Gradle Build Fails: Android Studio, Google Mobile Ads Highlighted

Tags: android, gradle, mobile, build, ads

When the gradle build fails it highlights all of my Google Mobile Ad components...

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    mAdView1 = findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView1.loadAd(adRequest1);
```

The ad was working fine yesterday and then the builds just started failing. It's happening across all of my projects on android studio. I have been searching for solutions. I have everything set up the way it should be as far as I know, as I said, it's been working just fine. Any ideas?

Edit...

I tried to add an edit but not sure if it's showing up so I'm editing it here...

Error:CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

is the error I get when I run or debug the project.

Comment: you should post your gradle error message

Comment: Error:CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Comment: thank you. that is the error I am getting.

Comment: run gradlew tasks and post the error message  as edit in the post above